# Android; How to Right Justify Buttons while other widgets stay Left Justified

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, justify

I'm new to Android and my app is finally working however I am having trouble with the layout.

The `xml` below is stripped down but where I marked it `<repeats>` I have 4 horizontal layouts.

Each with different widgets `Spinner`, `SeekBar` and `RadioButtons` all seperated by a divider.

Each you pick a setting and press the `Set` button to the right.

My issue, though all widget are neatly Left justified the vertical alignment of the buttons is all over the place.

If i just play with widget margins it will not fit right with different Android devices.

How can I get the `Buttons` vertically lined up to the right without moving all else from the left?

```
           GETTING                              WANT
 -------------------------------   -------------------------------- 
 | <Spinner>  <button>          |  | <Spinner>           <button> |      
 | < -------- Divider --------> |  | < -------- Divider --------> |
 | <RadioButton >  <button>     |  | <RadioButton>       <button> |
 | < -------- Divider --------> |  | < -------- Divider --------> |
 | <SeekBar>  <button>          |  | <SeekBar>           <button> |
 | < -------- Divider --------> |  | < -------- Divider --------> |
 | <RadioButton>       <button> |  | <RadioButton>       <button> |
 -------------------------------   --------------------------------
```

Here is my related code:

```
content_main.xml 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:scrollY="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<repeats>   <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/dynamic_TZ_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="223dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/TZ_btnSubmit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/set" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                android:visibility="visible" />
....            

            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:scrollY="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

 <repeats>   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/dynamic_TZ_spinner"
                android:layout_width="223dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TZ_btnSubmit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/set" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:visibility="visible" />
....            

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank You your change from lineal to relative WORKED

Answer (score 3):

Please try this Way and pay attention that when you want to put a widget in right or left of their parent, use " android:layout_alignParentRight="true" " or " android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" "

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
tools:scrollY="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
       
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_TZ_spinner"
            android:layout_width="223dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TZ_btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20"
            android:text="@string/set" />
     </RelativeLayout>
     <View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        ....

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `FrameLayout` and `layout_gravity` attributes in the children.

For one row use:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="Radio Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear Layout for each widget and button (coloumn)